# The CSRF token is missing

Tags: python, flask, csrf

I'm working with flask and trying to add a new rout that handles POST-request send by user in my js code.
When testing server(not using front), after my POST-request I get the issue

```
400 Bad Request
Bad Request
The CSRF token is missing
```

Here's my code for this request

```
@module.route('/check_answer', methods=['POST'], host=Config.HOST)

def check():
data = request.get_json()
user_ans = data['user_ans']
right_ans = data['right_ans']
return jsonify({'user_ans': user_ans, 'right_ans': right_ans})
```

I couldn't find the answer for this case, but if it exists can somebody share it with me?

Comment: Firstly, there's an indentation issue in your code. your ```check()``` function body needs to be indented properly. Secondly, how are you testing the request? Because Flask or Django require a CSRF token to be passed while making a request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a csrf_token to your form.

When using a FlaskForm, render the form's CSRF field like normal.

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>
```

If the template doesn't use a FlaskForm, render a hidden input with the token in the form.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm using button. So I've added this input and trying to test the route using client, but face with the problem again. Clicking the button I get the error  `"POST /check_answer HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Comment: Add the token to your button and try again

Comment: Should I add it just between the button tags?